# Extract an array from nested one

Tags: ruby

Any ideas to extract an array from a nested array?

From

```
[["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"], ["Paid", "$ 1"]]
```

To

```
  [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$2"]]
```

Also I want to have the retrieved element

```
["Paid", "$ 1"]
```

#### Update

I'd love to extract with the name.
`Total`, `Subtotal`,or `Paid`

Comment: IF `arr = [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"], ["Paid", "$ 1"]]` then `arr[0..1]` will gives you `[["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"]]`

Comment: The reference to "nested arrays" is a bit misleading as you simply want to extract elements from an array, elements that happen to be arrays.

Comment: Not clear. What makes `["Paid", "$ 1"]` special as compared to the other two elements? What is the logic to get `"$2"` from `"$ 2"` while getting `"$ 3"` from `"$ 3"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you question it is not clear exactly what problem you are trying to solve.

If you have other "keys" in the array and only want some specific items based on first item in subarray you should look into the assoc method:

```
array = [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"], ["Paid", "$ 1"]]

p array.assoc("Paid") #=> ["Paid", "$ 1"]
p ["Total","Subtotal"].map{|key| array.assoc key} #=> [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"]]
```

And if you want to mutate the original array I think doing it in two steps is the easiest solution:

```
item_index = array.find_index{|x| x.first == "Paid"}
paid = array.delete_at(item_index)

p paid #=> ["Paid", "$ 1"]
p array #=> [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [`Array#pop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-pop)

```rb
x = [1,2,3]  #=> [1, 2, 3]
x.pop        #=> 3
x            #=> [1, 2]
```

Instead of atomic values you will have your sub-arrays.

Comment: You should point out that this mutates the original array, something not expressly permitted by the question.

Comment: Nice to see you again @Cary %) I don't really know if it will be a useful chunk of information as the task seems too trivial to ask it on SO (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at following console o/p

```
[11] pry(main)> arr = [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"], ["Paid", "$ 1"]]
=> [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"], ["Paid", "$ 1"]]
[12] pry(main)> arr[0..1]
=> [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"]]
[13] pry(main)> arr[2]
=> ["Paid", "$ 1"]
```

As you want it on name 'total'

```
[17] pry(main)> arr = [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"], ["Paid", "$ 1"]]
=> [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"], ["Paid", "$ 1"]]
[18] pry(main)> arr.select{|ar| ar[0].downcase.include?('total')}
=> [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"]]
[19] pry(main)> arr.reject{|ar| ar[0].downcase.include?('total')}.first
=> ["Paid", "$ 1"]
[20] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'd love to extract it with the name Ex. 'Total'

Comment: Thank you! It works!! Is this possible to extract and delete the target element from original array? This would be cleaner.

Comment: Yes you have to use bang `!` methods for that, please read more about that. For now just change `select` to `select!`

Comment: but remember when you used `bang` methods it will change the calling object & you may lost the important data.

Comment: oh I mean [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"], ["Paid", "$ 1"]] with extraction of ["Paid", "$ 1"]. The original one should be [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"]]. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

```
original_array = [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"], ["Paid", "$ 1"]]

extract_array = original_array.values_at(-1).flatten
```

**output** : `["Paid", "$ 1"]`

```
remain_array = original_array - extract_array
```

**output** : `[["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"]]`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly:

```
input = [
  ["Total", "$ 3"],
  ["Subtotal", "$ 2"],
  ["Paid", "$ 1"]
]

input.to_h
#⇒ {
#      "Paid" => "$ 1",
#  "Subtotal" => "$ 2",
#     "Total" => "$ 3"
# }

input.to_h['Total']
#⇒ "$ 3"

my, rest = input.partition { |k, _| k == 'Total' }
my
#⇒ [["Total", "$ 3"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be :

```
*totals, paid = [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"], ["Paid", "$ 1"]]
totals # [["Total", "$ 3"], ["Subtotal", "$ 2"]]
paid   # ["Paid", "$ 1"]
```